# Prices are double at checkout

Tags: checkout, magento-1.9, cart, shopping

I have added configurable products with size and then added the simple products for each size.

When an item is added to shopping cart the price is doubled. If I remove the price from the configurable item i.e. set it to 0 then the price does not double.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Do you really want to add a price for both the simple and configurable? Surely one should add to the other as a default. My advise, just add the one price. Maybe add a 'base price' to the configurable, then for each of the options on the simple products, add an increment if it requires it.

> Configurable Base Price: 12.99
> Simple Size XL: 0.50
> Total Price at Checkout: 13.49
>
> ---
>
> Configurable Base Price: 12.99
> Simple Size XXL: 1.00
> Total Price at Checkout: 13.99
>
> ---
>
> Configurable Base Price: 12.99
> Simple Size XXXL: 1.50
> Total Price at Checkout: 14.49
>
> ---
>
> Configurable Base Price: 12.99
> Simple Size XXXXL: 2.00
> Total Price at Checkout: 14.99

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty much sure nothing has to be fixed here. If you create a configurable product and create the associated simple product, do not enter a price:

[image]

This field should only be used if a specific option requires a surcharge.